# Application_BeginRequest Event in global.asax in sharepoint

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, global-asax

First, I need to know where I can find `global.asax` file. I have already build Sharepoint Site, Now I need to create New Project in Visual Studio and then I need to trigger `Application_BeginRequest` so that I can get the User's Properties when Application Runs. So, how to find this file and how to inherit this to get `Application_BeginRequest` Event to run.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint default global.asax file path:

[image]

To custom http module in SharePoint, create a class inherit from `IHttpModule` and register it into SharePoint config file.

Demos:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-and-http-module/

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2015/02/18/when-using-a-custom-http-module-and-you-create-a-view-for-a-list-you-get-an-error-saying-cannot-complete-this-action-please-try-again/